# Can Java String handle 10^15 characters ?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Recently I came across a problem of handling a String of 10^15 characters !

Is it possible in Java?

Comment: It is not possible with a single String instance. Even if it were possible, it would not be a particularly bright idea.

Comment: I hope it doesn't represent a name.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: A `string` is backed by an array, meaning it has at most int.MAX_VALUE characters.